# Decrypting ASP.NET Auth Cookie Value without FormsAuthentication.Decrypt Method

Tags: asp.net, cryptography, aes

I try to read / decrypt the value of an auth cookie from forms authentication that is written in AES but without setting the MachineKey in the web.config because I cannot modify this config myself.

Therefore I can't use FormsAuthentication.Decrypt because this uses the machine key internally.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the ASP.NET version but in 2.0 and I *think* still in 4.0, you can override the machineKey in your web.config.

Check out the section "Web Farm Deployment Considerations".
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx#paght000007_webfarmdeploymentconsiderations

You can generate a machine key online with this tool: http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey